# Set number of gpus in PBS script from command line

Tags: shell, sh, distributed-computing, pbs

I'm invoking a job with `qsub myjob.pbs`. In there, I have some logic to run my experiments, which includes running `torchrun`, a distributed utility for pytorch. In that command you can set the number of nodes and number of processes (+gpus) per node. Depending on the availability, I want to be able to invoke qsub with an arbitrary number of GPUs, so that both `-l gpus=` and `torchrun --nproc_per_node=` are set depending on the command line argument.

I tried, the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
#PBS -l "nodes=1:ppn=12:gpus=$1"

torchrun --standalone --nnodes=1 --nproc_per_node=$1  myscript.py
```

and invoked it like so:

```bash
qsub --pass "4" myjob.pbs
```

but I got the following error: `ERROR: -l: gpus: expected valid integer, found '"$1"'`. Is there a way to pass the number of GPUs to the script so that the PBS directives can read them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your shell sees PBS directives as comments, so it will not be able to expand arguments in this way. This means that the expansion of `$1` will not be occur using:

```
#PBS -l "nodes=1:ppn=12:gpus=$1"
```

Instead, you can apply the `-l gpus=` argument on the command line and remove the directive from your PBS script. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
#PBS -l ncpus=12
set -eu

torchrun \
    --standalone \
    --nnodes=1 \
    --nproc_per_node="${nproc_per_node}" \
    myscript.py
```

Then just use a simple wrapper, e.g. `run_myjob.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -eu

qsub \
    -l gpus="$1" \
    -v nproc_per_node="$1" \
    myjob.pbs
```

Which should let you specify the number of gpus as a command-line argument:

```
sh run_myjob.sh 4
```

Comment: Aha, this is a nice way of going around it. Thanks!